Is there anyway to encrypt the disk without the TPM, and securely store the key?
I have a server that does not have TPM. I want to encrypt the disk (the /boot partition does not have to be encrypted). And I do not want to enter the passphrase during the boot.
So there must be a place where I can securely store the passphrase. However, I searched the Internet, and found the way to do this is by putting the key in the initramfs. Since the boot partition is not encrypted, therefore it is easy for the attacker to get the passphrase (in the initramfs).
So,is there any trick that can securely store the passphrase, while enabling boot without user interaction?

You could use a hardware fingerprint, esoteric example - but at most it will only help if the drive is removed from the system altogether. Also prone to breaking.
